# How to track events on $scope.$broadcast?

Tags: angularjs, broadcast, angular-broadcast

I'm using angular-timer and I'm just a little confused how to track its events. For example, I want to do something after time is up, but I can't see any events on console log.

```
  vm.add20Seconds = function() {
    $scope.$broadcast('timer-add-cd-seconds', 20);
  }

  $scope.$on('timer-add-cd-seconds', function (event, data) {
    console.log(data); // 'Some data'
  });
```

The console is empty.

https://github.com/siddii/angular-timer/blob/master/examples/angularjs-add-countdown-seconds.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As the code given in link is not seems to be updated, I think you changed it to use `controllerAs` syntax. So your `button` html will use `vm` alias while calling controller method. Assuming you used `ng-controller="MyAppController as vm"`

**Markup**

```
<button type="button" ng-click="vm.add20Seconds()">Add 20 Seconds</button>
```

Else wanted to use `$scope` in your controller then simply change method to `$scope.add20Seconds` instead of `vm.add20Seconds`

**Update**

To get call a function after `20` seconds over, you could use `$timeout` service here, that will call and specified callback when mentioned `$timeout` completed.

**Code**

```
vm.add20Seconds = function() {
   $scope.$broadcast('timer-add-cd-seconds', 20);
}

var myCallbackAfterTimeout = function(){
   //add your code.
}

$scope.$on('timer-add-cd-seconds', function (event, data) {
 console.log(data); // 'Some data'
 $timeout(myCallbackAfterTimeout, data); //data is nothing but timeout milliseconds
});
```

> Include `$timeout` dependency in your controller before using it.

Comment: Yes, I know. Adding seconds is working. I want to implement callback after time is up, but I can't see any events on 'timer-add-cd-seconds' broadcast.

Comment: @VitalyFry You question looks confusing kindly update it..for your concern you should use `$timeout`/`$interval`

Answer (score 0):

if you are looking for a good article about using the scope tree As A Publish And Subscribe (Pub/Sub) mechanism in angularJS please check this [link](http://www.bennadel.com/blog/2734-using-the-scope-tree-as-a-publish-and-subscribe-pub-sub-mechanism-in-angularjs.htm)